# check if conda environment has changed

Tags: conda

I am changing my conda environment in a slurm script, so I want to make sure the environment has changed to what I intended. How can I do that?

I see codes for "setting" the environment variable, but I didn't find anything for "getting" the environment variable. (if this is even what I need).

Answer (score 1):

The `conda info --envs` command will show every conda environment that is currently accessible along with its location. This command can be used in your slurm script to see if the desired environment is present.

In order to verify whether the conda environment has been active or not, you can also use the `which python` command before and after doing so.

In your slurm script, make sure to include `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` before activating the environment. This is due to the fact that your `~/.bashrc` is not supplied when slurm jobs are being done, which prevents it from initialising the shell for Conda environments.

Comment: Thanks! `which python` is what I was looking for! I add `source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` before activating the environment. Do I still need to use `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"`